# Keep only first and last element of sublists in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list such as : `[[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[9,10,11],[12,13,14],[15]]`

How can I select within each sublist only the first and last element, such as :

```
expected_list=[[0,2],[3,5],[6,8],[9,11],[12,14],[15]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use list comprehension:

```
l = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[9,10,11],[12,13,14],[15]]


expected_list = [[x[0], x[-1]] if len(x) > 1 else [x[0]] for x in l]
```

To be on the safe side, you could also check for empty lists:

```
[[x[0], x[-1]] if len(x) > 1 else [x[0]] if len(x) else [] for x in l]
```

Alternative:

```
[x[0::len(x)-1] if len(x) > 1 else x.copy() for x in l]
```

(`x.copy()` thanks to @mozway see comment)

Comment: or `[[x[0], x[-1]] if len(x) > 1 else x.copy() for x in l]`

Comment: @mozway: yes, this is even better

Answer (score 2):

Another variation using destructuring with a pinch of asterisk:

```py
[[a, b[-1]] if b else [a] for a, *b in my_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
inp = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[9,10,11],[12,13,14],[15]]
outp = [[x[0], x[-1]] for x in inp]
```

This makes the last element [15, 15] though - if that is not acceptable, you can use this:

```
outp = [[x[0], x[-1]] if len(x) > 1 else [x[0]] for x in inp ]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is clumsy way.
Just look for fun.

```
da_list = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[9,10,11],[12,13,14],[15]]
result = []
for i in da_list :
    try :
        i.pop(1)
    except: continue    
    result.append(i)
print (result)
```